# Differ vs. Different

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-request

I have a technical document and one of its sections is entitled

> Hypervisors vs. emulators

The next section is entitled

> How they differ from Docker and ScummVM

Is it correct? Or maybe I should use the word "different" instead, i.e.

> How they are different from Docker and ScummVM

?

Comment: Neither is a proper question in English.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, I understand that usually it's better to ask "What is the difference between..." Here is my case: I have a technical document, and one of its sections is entitled "Hypervisors vs. emulators" (to describe the difference between them). The next section is entitled "How they differ from Docker and ScummVM". What you suggest in this case?

Comment: "How they differ from Docker and ScummVM" is not a question.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, the sentence ends with a period instead of a question mark. In such a case, should I use a) "How they _differ_ from ..." or b) "How they _different_ from..." or c) something different? I could edit the question.

Comment: The sentence is not a question because it does not end with a question mark, but more fundamentally, because it lacks an auxiliary verb, This is a question: "How do ethics differ from etiquette?" and so is this: "How are ethics different from etiquette?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"How they differ from Docker and ScummVM" and "How they are different from Docker and ScummVM" are equally valid as section titles. Choosing between them is merely a matter of preference or style. The former seems more professional to me, because it is more direct and concise.

Answer (score 4):

*Differ* is a verb.  You can say *X differs from Y* or ask "how does X differ from Y".

*Difference* is a noun.  Things have differences from each other, or you ask what the difference is between two things.

So, if you use *difference*, you need a verb in the sentence such as *have* or most often a form of *be*.

*X has a difference from Y*, *What is the difference between X and Y*.

Comment: Upvoted. Yes, I always use "What is the difference between construction". However, my case is slightly different and is currently described in the comments. I will edit my question right now to prevent further confusion.